# How can I map multipul lists to one key on C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to map one string (sentence) in to two lists (similar sentences indexes and the different word in each one).
By using "Dictionary" I have to use 2 dictionaries to save each list.

Is there other way to save a string as a key to int[] and string[]?

this is how it lookes now:

```
Dictionary<string, int[]> similarSentences = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
Dictionary<string, string[]> changes = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
```

I want someting like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int[],string[]> similarSentencesAndChanges = new Dictionary<string, int[],string[]>();
```

Thank you!

Comment: While you *could* use a tuple, I suggest you create your own type as the value part of the dictionary - your type would contain both arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are ok to use tuples, you could create an extension method for the generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` type, which returns a dictionary with tuple values...

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, (TValue, TValue2)> Combine<TKey, TValue, TValue2>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> a, Dictionary<TKey, TValue2> b)
{
    return a.Keys.Union(b.Keys).ToDictionary(x => x, x => (
        a.ContainsKey(x) ? a[x] : default,
        b.ContainsKey(x) ? b[x] : default
    ));
}
```

Example usage...

```
var similarSentencesAndChanges = similarSentences.Combine(changes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use tuples:

```
Dictionary<string,(int[] Similar, string[] Changes)> similarSentencesAndChanges = new Dictionary<string,(int[] Similar, string[] Changes)>();
```

and then you can access it like this:

```
var someKey = "somekey";
(int[] similar, string[] changes) = similarSentencesAndChanges[someKey];
```

However, depending on what you plan to do, randomly using tuples is a bad practice and you'd be wise in creating a class that contains both collections.

```
class SentenceData
{
    public int[] Similar {get;}

    public string[] Changes {get;}
}
```

Then, make your dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, SentenceData>`.

This has the added benefit of allowing the reuse of the object in other parts of your code. Furthermore, adding properties to the object at a latter stage won't involve potentially rewriting large parts of your code.